# Problem looping through array of coordinates from database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, android-mapview

I can parse data from the database but having a hard time looping through all the coordinates in the database and plotting them on the mapview. Can someone please help.

```
-(void)scanDatabase{

  UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
  NSString *uid = [device uniqueIdentifier];
  NSString *myUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://address.php?uid=%@",uid];
  NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: myUrl ]];    

  // to receive the returend value
  NSString *serverOutput =[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSArray *components = [serverOutput componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

  for (NSString *line in components) {
    NSArray *fields = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@"\t"];
    [eventPoints addObjectsFromArray:fields];

    int count = [fields count];
    for(int i=0;i < count; i++) {
      int myindex0 = i*count;
      int myindex1 = (i*count)+1;
      int myindex2 = (i*count)+2;

      NSString *mytitle = [eventPoints objectAtIndex:myindex0];
      NSNumber *myLat = [eventPoints objectAtIndex:myindex1];
      NSNumber *myLon = [eventPoints objectAtIndex:myindex2];

      CLLocationCoordinate2D loc;

      loc.latitude = myLat.doubleValue;
      loc.longitude = myLon.doubleValue;

      customAnnotation *event = [[customAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:loc];
      event.title = mytitle;

      MKPinAnnotationView *newAnnotationPin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:event reuseIdentifier:@"simpleAnnotation"];
      newAnnotationPin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;

      [map addAnnotation:event];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what problems you are experiencing since "having a hard time..." doesn't describe them very well :-)

Looking at your code I like to make the following comments:

- The inner loop doesn't seem to make any sense.
- Why don't you access the fields directly?
- myLat and myLon should be NSString object references.

Maybe something like this works better:

```
-(void)scanDatabase{

  UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
  NSString *uid = [device uniqueIdentifier];
  NSString *myUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://address.php?uid=%@",uid];
  NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: myUrl ]];    

  // to receive the returend value
  NSString *serverOutput =[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSArray *components = [serverOutput componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

  for (NSString *line in components) {
    NSArray *fields = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@"\t"];
    [eventPoints addObjectsFromArray:fields];

    if ( [fields count] != 3 ) {
      // something is wrong/unexpected here, act appropriately
    }
    else {
      NSString *mytitle = [fields objectAtIndex:0];
      NSString *myLat = [fields objectAtIndex:1];
      NSString *myLon = [fields objectAtIndex:2];

      CLLocationCoordinate2D loc;

      loc.latitude = myLat.doubleValue;
      loc.longitude = myLon.doubleValue;

      customAnnotation *event = [[customAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:loc];
      event.title = mytitle;

      MKPinAnnotationView *newAnnotationPin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:event reuseIdentifier:@"simpleAnnotation"];
      newAnnotationPin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;

      [map addAnnotation:event];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Volker, that's what I was looking for.. The ifelse statement worked.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the delegate method to add the annotation view

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

otherwise it will never appear see here
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *newAnnotationPin = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"simpleAnnotation"] autorelease];
        newAnnotationPin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    return newAnnotationPin;
}
```

Comment: Thank you bigkm, but the problem is with the iteration through the array of coordinates from the database and then adding the annotation to the map.

Comment: I moved the code into the delegate method, now I can't see my current position...